# Node cluster not spawning phantom instances in the proper worker

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, cluster-computing, child-process, node-cluster

I'm using NodeJS with PhantomJS. My goal is to create 4x node instances with node cluster, each with 2 phantom children. And my code looks like this:

cluster.js:

```
var numCPUs = 4;

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
        cluster.fork();
    });

} else {
    require("./app");
}
```

App.js looks like this:

```
var instances = [];
var phantom = require('phantom');

function InstanceManager(instCount) {
    for (var i = 0; i < instCount; i++) {
           phantom.create(function(phantomInstance) {
            instances.push({
                cycle: 0,
                locked: false,
                instance: phantomInstance
            });
        });
    }
}

InstanceManager(2);

setInterval(function() {
    var i = 0;
    console.log('--' + instances.length);
}, 5000);
```

So after running `cluster.js` the expected output in node console each 5 seconds should be:

```
--2
--2
--2
--2
```

but instead looks like this:

```
--0
--0
--0
--8
```

Why the phantom instances aren't attached to the proper worker?

Comment: What happens when you increase the `setInterval` timeout to 10000 or 15000? The starting of 2 instances may be too slow for 5 seconds or even 10 seconds.

Comment: Still the same result :(

Comment: I'm running node 0.10.26 and it works

Comment: @Deepsy Interesting problem!!!  I completed my answer today, it's below.  I had to leave out the details, but I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the phantom module, not working properly with the cluster.  If you replace it with a sort of test double, like

```
var phantom = {
    create: function (callback) {
        setImmediate(callback);
    }
};
```

you get the expected all-2 output.  To continue my investigation, I modified `node_modules/phantom/phantom.js` to get a minimal set up where your problem occurs.  This is it:

```
var http = require('http'), shoe = require('shoe'), spawn = require('win-spawn');

exports.create = function(cb) {
    var httpServer, sock;
    httpServer = http.createServer();
    httpServer.listen(0);
    httpServer.on('listening', function() {
        var listeningPort = httpServer.address().port;
        spawn('phantomjs', [].concat([__dirname + '/shim.js', listeningPort]));
    });
    sock = shoe(cb);
    return sock.install(httpServer, '/dnode');
};
```

What happens here is that a listening server is started, then a phantomjs process is started, which connects to the listening server via a WebSocket, and writes to it, after which the callback `cb()` is called.  You can get at this understanding by looking at `shim.js` and experimenting a bit.

What's the problem then!?  Well, if you `console.log()` the `listeningPort` you will see that you get the same port 8 times.  So it appears that every time you call `phantom.create()`, you somehow reuse the same listening server, hence your callback is called only in one process.

This seems to be a peculiar behaviour of the Node version you're using, when trying to listen on port 0.  Which would also explain why with another version of Node, the problem didn't occur (according to a comment 
above).  Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/idrarig/f4b95a47d78fef287853) of mine which isolates this counter-intuitive behaviour.

The solution is to specify a port when calling `phantom.create()`, and use 8 different ports, e.g., `phantom.create(fn, { port: YOUR_PORT })` in your `app.js`.

Comment: Excellent! You da real MVP!